# JavaFx and memory consumption

Tags: java, memory, javafx

I just made an application with java fx that cycles videos in a folder.
I had to set the next video firing the setonendofmedia event, so they are in a cycle, but the problem is that the application loads every video at the beginning, so after a while it fills memory and crashes.
Is there another way to cycle videos without pre-load them or a way to flush memory every while?

This is my code :

```
 package application;


    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FilenameFilter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
    import javafx.scene.media.Media;
    import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
    import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

    class SceneGenerator {    

        private int xSize;
        private int ySize;

        public SceneGenerator(int xSize,int ySize){
            this.xSize=xSize;
            this.ySize=ySize;
        }

      public Scene createScene() {
        final StackPane layout = new StackPane();

        // determine the source directory for the playlist
        final File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\video");
        if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cannot find video source directory: " + dir);
          Platform.exit();
          System.exit(0);
          return null;
        }

        //inizializzo il toolkit


        // create some media players.
        final List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
        for (String file : dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
          @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".mp4")||name.endsWith(".flv");
          }
        })) players.add(createPlayer("file:///" + (dir + "\\" + file).replace("\\", "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20")));
        if (players.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.println("No video found in " + dir);
          Platform.exit();
          System.exit(0);
          return null;
        }    

        // create a view to show the mediaplayers.
        final MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(players.get(0));

            mediaView.setPreserveRatio(false);
            mediaView.setFitHeight(ySize-((ySize/100)*(JavaPlayer.panelSouthYDimension+1)-JavaPlayer.pixelAdattamento));
            mediaView.setFitWidth(xSize);


        // play each audio file in turn.
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
          final MediaPlayer player     = players.get(i);
          final MediaPlayer nextPlayer = players.get((i + 1) % players.size());



          player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
              mediaView.setMediaPlayer(nextPlayer);
              nextPlayer.seek(nextPlayer.getStartTime());
              nextPlayer.play();
            }
          });
        }






        // start playing the first track.
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(players.get(0));
        mediaView.getMediaPlayer().play();



        // layout the scene.
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black; -fx-font-size: 20; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-alignment: center;");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(
          VBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(
            mediaView).build()
        );

        return new Scene(layout);
      }

      /** sets the currently playing label to the label of the new media player and updates the progress monitor. */


      /** @return a MediaPlayer for the given source which will report any errors it encounters */
      private MediaPlayer createPlayer(String aMediaSrc) {
    //    System.out.println("Creating player for: " + aMediaSrc);
        final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(aMediaSrc));
        player.setOnError(new Runnable() {
          @Override public void run() {
            System.out.println("Media error occurred: " + player.getError());
          }
        });
        return player;
      }
    }
```

Hi thanks for the code, I'm currently using java 7 and all is working good, but once a video is loaded it is never released so the memory consumption is still high.
I tried using system.gc, but it seems not to be enough. Some suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
class SceneGenerator {    

private int xSize;
private int ySize;

public SceneGenerator(int xSize,int ySize){
    this.xSize=xSize;
    this.ySize=ySize;
}
```

public Scene createScene() {
    final StackPane layout = new StackPane();

```
// determine the source directory for the playlist
final File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\video");
if (!dir.exists() || !dir.isDirectory()) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cannot find video source directory: " + dir);
  Platform.exit();
  System.exit(0);
  return null;
}

//inizializzo il toolkit


final MediaView mediaView = new MediaView();

    mediaView.setPreserveRatio(false);
    mediaView.setFitHeight(ySize-((ySize/100)*(JavaPlayer.panelSouthYDimension+1)-JavaPlayer.pixelAdattamento));
    mediaView.setFitWidth(xSize);


    final int QUEUE_SIZE = 2 ; // should be enough
    final BlockingQueue<MediaPlayer> playerQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);


    final Thread createPlayerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             // create some media players.
            List<String> videoFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String file : dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
              @Override public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".mp4")||name.endsWith(".flv");
              }
            })) videoFiles.add("file:///" + (dir + "\\" + file).replace("\\", "/").replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
            int nextFileIndex = 0 ;

            while (true) {
                System.gc();
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(videoFiles.get(nextFileIndex).toString())); // create
                player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final Task<MediaPlayer> nextPlayerTask = new Task<MediaPlayer>() {
                            @Override
                            public MediaPlayer call()  {
                                try {
                                    return playerQueue.take();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in SceneGenerator() : "+e.getMessage());
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        nextPlayerTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
                                MediaPlayer player = nextPlayerTask.getValue();
                                mediaView.setMediaPlayer(player);
                                player.play();
                            }
                        });
                        new Thread(nextPlayerTask).start();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    playerQueue.put(player); // this will block if the queue is full...
                } catch (InterruptedException exc ) { // shouldn't happen...
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                    return ;
                }
                nextFileIndex = (nextFileIndex + 1) % videoFiles.size();
            }
        }
    });
    createPlayerThread.setDaemon(true); // won't block application exit

    // Layout etc

    createPlayerThread.start();
    // start first player. In theory, this could block, so call it before you show the stage:
    MediaPlayer firstPlayer;
    try {
        firstPlayer = playerQueue.take();
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(firstPlayer);
        firstPlayer.play();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in SceneGenerator() : "+e.getMessage());
    }



// layout the scene.
layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black; -fx-font-size: 20; -fx-padding: 0; -fx-alignment: center;");
layout.getChildren().addAll(
  VBoxBuilder.create().spacing(10).alignment(Pos.CENTER).children(
    mediaView).build()
);

return new Scene(layout);
```

}

}

Comment: I'm not super familiar with javaFX, but, I am pretty familiar with how garbage collect works.  Just at a glance (and maybe I just missed it), but it doesn't look like you're getting rid of the items in your players arraylist.  I imagine those items take a ton of memory and by keeping a reference to them in the arraylist, you prevent the GC from freeing the memory.  Maybe you could also wait to create the player (and only store the file path) until it's ready to be played (or the next in queue).  Sorry if this wasn't helpful, like I said, I'm not very familiar with javaFX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by creating a `BlockingQueue<MediaPlayer>` to store a limited number of media players. Create a background thread that loops through the files, creates a media player from each file, and puts it in the queue. The media player should have the `onEndOfMedia` listener registered with it. That listener will be more or less as you have it, but you take the next MediaPlayer from the queue (this should be in a background thread too) and play it. It gets slightly more complicated because you have to manage threads as you have blocking calls, but something like this (this is just approximate to give you the idea; I haven't tested it or tried to compile or anything):

```
    final int QUEUE_SIZE = 2;
    final BlockingQueue<MediaPlayer> playerQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);
    final MediaView mediaView = new MediaView();


    Thread createPlayerThread = new Thread( () -> {
        final List<File> videoFiles = ...
        IntStream.iterate(0, index -> (index + 1) % videoFiles.size())
            .mapToObj(videoFiles::get)
            .map(file -> createPlayer(file, mediaView, playerQueue))
            .forEach(player -> {
                try {
                    playerQueue.put(player);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return ;
                }
            });
    });
    createPlayerThread.setDaemon(true);
    createPlayerThread.start();

    // do layout, etc...

    try {
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(playerQueue.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ...

private MediaPlayer createPlayer(File file, MediaView mediaView, BlockingQueue<MediaPlayer> playerQueue) {
    URI uri = file.toURI();
    Media media = new Media(uri.toString());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setAutoPlay(true);
    player.setOnEndOfMedia( () -> {
        Task<MediaPlayer> nextPlayerTask = new Task<MediaPlayer>() {
            @Override
            protected MediaPlayer call() throws Exception {
                return playerQueue.take();
            }
        };
        nextPlayerTask.setOnSucceeded(workerStateEvent -> 
            mediaView.setMediaPlayer(nextPlayerTask.getValue()));
    });
    return player ;
}
```

If the queue size is too big, then you run the risk of running out of memory. If it's too small, then in theory you could risk not having any videos available in the queue (if they took longer to load than play); in practice this is probably unlikely. The code will still work if the queue size is too small, but there would be pauses between the videos.

Comment: This would be a lot cleaner in Java 8. If you're using Java 8, let me know and I'll edit the code.

Comment: Hello, 
I thank you for the answer! 
I tried your code, there was some mistake, but fixing it works really well. Before the program consumed about 600 MB of RAM, now consumes about 300 MB! If you can create the same code to java 8 I can test it. 
Thanks again

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, I'm currently using java 7 and all is working good, but once a video is loaded it is never released so the memory consumption is still high. I tried using system.gc, but it seems not to be enough. Some suggestion? Thanks in advance. (i added code my code in the answer)

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I wonder if the endOfMedia handler is preventing the player from getting garbage collected. I don't quite see why that would be, but it's my best guess. You could try setting that to null when it's no longer needed.

Comment: I can not solve it.I tried your code in jre8 but not change a video.